The progress bar stuck at 100% in notification bar when download file from internet
I was downloading a pdf from url and save in  app storage this code work as it download file and save in app storage and notify user about download in notification bar
But the problem are occur some time the file is downloaded and save in app storage but  progress bar stuck in 100%  and doesnt go to Download Complete notification
Screenshot is
as it stuck in 100% but  it already download in storage
FileUtils
private const val CANCEL_DOWNLOAD_ACTION = "com.example.library.CANCEL_DOWNLOAD"
suspend fun downloadBookContent(context: Context, bookURL: String, fileName: String): String =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val channelId = "download_channel"
        createNotificationChannel(notificationManager, channelId)
//        val cancelIntent = Intent(CANCEL_DOWNLOAD_ACTION)
//        val cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
//            context, 0, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
//        )
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Downloading $fileName")
            .setContentText("Downloading in progress")
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, com.poditivity.common.R.color.primary))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setProgress(100, 0, false)
//            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, "Cancel", cancelPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())

        var isCancelled = false
        var isReceiverRegistered = false

        val cancelReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                isCancelled = true
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download cancelled")
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .clearActions()
                notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())

                val tempFile = File(context?.cacheDir, "temp_$fileName")
                if (tempFile.exists()) {
                    tempFile.delete()
                }
                if (isReceiverRegistered) {
                    try {
                        context?.unregisterReceiver(this)
                        isReceiverRegistered = false
                    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                        Log.w("CancelReceiver", "Receiver not registered or already unregistered")
                    }
                }
                notificationManager.cancel(1)
                throw CancellationException("Download cancelled")
            }
        }
        context.registerReceiver(cancelReceiver, IntentFilter(CANCEL_DOWNLOAD_ACTION), null, null, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        isReceiverRegistered = true

        try {
            val url = URL(bookURL)
            val connection = url.openConnection()
            connection.connect()

            var fileLength = connection.contentLength
            var totalBytesRead = 0
            if (fileLength <= 0) {
                fileLength = 1
            }

            BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()).use { inputStream ->
                val tempFile = File(context.cacheDir, "temp_$fileName")
                BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(tempFile)).use { outputStream ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(8 * 1024) // 8 KB buffer
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        val progress = (totalBytesRead * 100 / fileLength).coerceIn(0, 100)
                        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false)
                            .setContentText("$progress%")
                            .setOngoing(true)
                        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
                        if (isCancelled) {
                            tempFile.delete()
                            throw CancellationException("Download cancelled")
                        }
                    }
                }
                context.unregisterReceiver(cancelReceiver)
                isReceiverRegistered = false

                val compressedFile = File(context.filesDir, "$fileName.gz")
                compressFile(tempFile, compressedFile)
                tempFile.delete()

                val openFragmentIntent = Intent(context, LibraryActivity::class.java).apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    putExtra("destination", "savedBooks")
                }
                val openFragmentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, openFragmentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, com.poditivity.common.R.color.primary))
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(openFragmentPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .clearActions()

                notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
                return@withContext compressedFile.absolutePath
            }
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            throw e
        } finally {
            if (isReceiverRegistered) {
                try {
                    context.unregisterReceiver(cancelReceiver)
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    Log.w("DownloadTryBlock", "Receiver not registered or already unregistered")
                }
            }
        }
    }

private fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager, channelId: String) {
    val channel = NotificationChannel(
        channelId,
        "Download Notifications",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
    )
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)


ViewModel
    fun saveBookLocally(context: Context, book: Book) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val fileName = "book_${book.bookId}"
                val localPath = downloadBookContent(context, book.bookURL, fileName)
                if (localPath.isNotEmpty()) {
                    libraryRepository.saveBookLocally(book)
                    Log.d("BookLocalPath", "Saving book, local path: $localPath")
                    libraryRepository.updateLocalPath(book.bookId, localPath)
                } else {
                    Log.d("SaveLocallyException", "Local path is null or empty, not saving book.")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("SaveLocallyException", e.toString())
            }
            fetchAllBooks()
        }
    }

Fragment
  private fun savePdf() {
        val book = Book(
            bookId = args.bookId,
            bookName = args.bookName,
            bookURL = args.bookUrl,
            username = args.bookCreator
        )
        viewModel.saveBookLocally(requireContext(), book)
    }
    override fun setUpClickListeners() {
        binding.imgSave.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val book = viewModel.getBookById(args.bookId)
                if(book!=null){
                    viewModel.deleteBookOffline(requireContext(), book)
                    binding.imgSave.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_save)
                    showSnackBar("${args.bookName}  is deleted")
                }else {
                    savePdf()
                    showSnackBar("${args.bookName} downloading...")
                    binding.imgSave.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_filled)
                }
            }
        }

I tried search in internet but didnt find any solution
I  was achieving that when  download compelete instant show download complete notification bar
Any references code will be helpful
All Logs
2024-07-15 13:04:52.139  9496-9605  Download  D  Starting download: https://css4.pub/2017/newsletter/drylab.pdf


2024-07-15 13:04:54.934  9496-9605  Download    D  Progress: 100%
2024-07-15 13:04:54.938  9496-9605  Download   D  Download completed. Compressing file...
2024-07-15 13:04:55.031  9496-9605  Download  D  File compressed and saved at: /data/user/0/com.poditivity/files/book_3.gz
2024-07-15 13:04:55.036  9496-9605  Download D  Download complete notification shown

As it shown the Download Notification are show but in notification bar are not updated
